# How do I make HDMI my default audio out?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm running Kubuntu 22.10 and when I wake from sleep or reboot I have to go into pulse audio voloume control and change the internal RS780 card from off to HDMI on the configuration tab, I then have to go over to the playback tab and click HDMI out next to firefox, is there any way to make pulse audio remember my settings?